# Informatica Plugin for Vertica

Tags: informatica, vertica

I'm trying to get our Informatica Powercenter 9.1 to connect to Vertica 7.1 and I'm running into the following error.

> 2014-11-21 14:21:09 : INFO : (29798 | 140249353135872) : (RS |
>   1servername-repository) : node-1 : CNX_53117 : Repository service
>   process failed to process request ID 2, request operation code 55,
>   reply operation code 55. Return Status: 6.

We're following the tutorial and the error is happening at the step where we register the vertica.xml plugin file into the repository.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: While doing a Proof-Of-Concept (before you get familiar with all the tricks) contacting Informatica might be very useful. And many times it's a must, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a permissions issue on the Informatica repository.